# Can analytic functions be used to find a subset of words that begin other words?

Tags: sql, oracle

Not a duplicate: my other question with the same title targets MySQL, this one targets oracle

I’m trying to find a single pass way of traversing an ordered list of words, looking for the shortest previous word that the current word begins with

Essentially in the following list (2 columns, varchar,int):

```
'APP',3
'APPLE',2
'APPLICATION',7
'BOW',2
'BRA',6
'BRAVE',5
'BRAVERY',3
'CANED',2
'CANES',4
```

I’d like to eliminate APPLE, APPLICATION, BRAVE and BRAVERY but add their numerical scores to the root word that they start with, so APP scores 3+2+7 and BRA scores 6+5+3

```
'APP',12
'BRA',14
'BOW',2
'CANED',2
'CANES',4
```

Though bravery starts with brave and bra, its root word is bra, because bra is shorter than brave

I get the feeling it can be done by creating a column that increments each time the current row word doesn’t start with any previous row word and the current row word is not longer than the previous row word, then use that as a partition.. It’s the “with any previous row word” bit that I’m stuck on- essentially Apple and Application both start with App, but Application doesn’t start with Apple (and bravery does start with brave) so comparing the immediate previous row for being like the current row doesn’t work

I can already do this using joins and variables in MySQL and SQLS, and joins (joining the table back to itself a few times) in Oracle.. I’m wondering if there’s a one hit way that avoids all use of joining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you can solve this problem easily with the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause. The catch is that `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` requires Oracle version 12.1 or higher.

`MATCH_RECOGNIZE` has some of the features of analytic functions, but it adds a few more of its own. In the solution below, the critical part is the ability to mark rows as either "root" (I named them `r`) or "extension" (`e`) in a single pass, while being able to - in the same pass - recognize where one "group" ( one *match*, in technical terms) ends and the next one begins - and to also sum the values for each match, still in the same pass.

I don't think you can do the same as easily just with analytic functions.

**NOTE**: For older versions of Oracle, the problem can be solved with the `MODEL` clause (also proprietary to Oracle). This requires Oracle 10.1 or higher. Solution provided at the bottom of this ANSWER (after the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` solution).

```
with
  simulated_data(word, val) as (
    select 'APP'        , 3 from dual union all
    select 'APPLE'      , 2 from dual union all
    select 'APPLICATION', 7 from dual union all
    select 'BOW'        , 2 from dual union all
    select 'BRA'        , 6 from dual union all
    select 'BRAVE'      , 5 from dual union all
    select 'BRAVERY'    , 3 from dual union all
    select 'CANED'      , 2 from dual union all
    select 'CANES'      , 4 from dual
  )
select root_word, total_value
from   simulated_data
match_recognize(
  order by word
  measures r.word   as root_word,
           sum(val) as total_value
  pattern  ( r e* )
  define   e as e.word like r.word || '%'
)
;

ROOT_WORD   TOTAL_VALUE
----------- -----------
APP                  12
BOW                   2
BRA                  14
CANED                 2
CANES                 4
```

Solution using the `MODEL` clause:

```
with
  simulated_data(word, val) as (
    select 'APP'        , 3 from dual union all
    select 'APPLE'      , 2 from dual union all
    select 'APPLICATION', 7 from dual union all
    select 'BOW'        , 2 from dual union all
    select 'BRA'        , 6 from dual union all
    select 'BRAVE'      , 5 from dual union all
    select 'BRAVERY'    , 3 from dual union all
    select 'CANED'      , 2 from dual union all
    select 'CANES'      , 4 from dual
  )
select rw as root_word, tv as total_value
from   (
         select rw, tv, fl
         from   simulated_data
         model
           dimension by (row_number() over (order by word) as rn)
           measures     (word, val, rpad('x', 4000, 'x') as rw, 0 as tv, 0 as fl)
           rules        (
             rw[any] = case instr(word[cv()], rw[cv()-1]) 
                            when 1 then rw[cv()-1] else word[cv()] end,
             tv[any] = case rw[cv()] when rw[cv()-1] 
                            then tv[cv()-1] + val[cv()] else val[cv()] end,
             fl[any] = case rw[cv()] when rw[cv()+1] 
                            then 0 else 1 end
           )
       )
where  fl = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a `CASE WEHN` with `LIKE` in `GROUP BY`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
(CASE
    WHEN name LIKE 'APP%' THEN 'APP'
    WHEN name LIKE 'BRA%' THEN 'BRA'
    ELSE name
END) name,SUM(amount) 
FROM T
GROUP BY 
CASE
    WHEN name LIKE 'APP%' THEN 'APP'
    WHEN name LIKE 'BRA%' THEN 'BRA'
    ELSE name
END
```

---

If you don't want to use `CASE WEHN` with `LIKE` in `GROUP BY`.

I would create a `mapper` table for your keyword name, because you need to tell the programme which is your expect keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE T(name varchar(50),amount int);

insert into t values ('APP',3);
insert into t values ('APPLE',2);
insert into t values ('APPLICATION',7);
insert into t values ('BOW',2);
insert into t values ('BRA',6);
insert into t values ('BRAVE',5);
insert into t values ('BRAVERY',3);
insert into t values ('CANED',2);
insert into t values ('CANES',4);

CREATE TABLE maaper(
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO maaper VALUES ('APP');
INSERT INTO maaper VALUES ('BRA');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT coalesce(t2.name,t1.name) name,sum(AMOUNT)
FROM T t1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name 
    FROM maaper
) t2 ON t1.name like  t2.name || '%'
group by coalesce(t2.name,t1.name)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66b07/2/0)**:

```
|  NAME | SUM(AMOUNT) |
|-------|-------------|
|   BRA |          14 |
| CANED |           2 |
|   APP |          12 |
| CANES |           4 |
|   BOW |           2 |
```

Comment: I doubt that your reading (understanding) of the problem statement is correct. Which words should be "roots" must be part of the work performed by the query; they shouldn't be hard coded, and there should be no assumption that the roots will be known before the query is run.